# Simple XAML VisualStateManager

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

Good day,

I'm learning the basics of XAML and currently on the VisualSateManager topic.

I am trying to get a very simple code to work: To change the color and font size of the window when resized... However, it does not work. The "app" launches fine but resizing does not change anything.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```xaml
<Grid Name="ColorGrid" Background="Pink">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStatePhone">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="ColorGrid.Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Target="MessageTextBlock.Fontsize" Value="18"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateTablet">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="ColorGrid.Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                        <Setter Target="MessageTextBlock.Fontsize" Value="40"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateDesktop">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="800"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="ColorGrid.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                        <Setter Target="MessageTextBlock.Fontsize" Value="60"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <TextBlock Name="MessageTextBlock" Text="Hello I am forgetting something"/>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property names are case sensitive. Change these:

```
<Setter Target="MessageTextBlock.Fontsize" Value="60"/>
```

...to this (note `FontSize` rather than `Fontsize`):

```
<Setter Target="MessageTextBlock.FontSize" Value="60"/>
```

(There are three occurrences.)

The color changes worked for me just by copying your XAML, provided I just *ran* the program (Ctrl+F5). Starting the debugger (F5) resulted in a pink background.

Comment: Thanks. The FontSize was the problem. I feel so silly right now.